# Soap UI delay configuration

Tags: soapui, delay

We have to design a Soap UI script, where there will be 15 threads triggered simultaneously ,with a delay 0f 1 second, the 15 request will iterate till we achieve the target of 100 requests. After achieving the target 100 request, all the threads should wait for 5 mins and again it will perform the same action.

Kindly suggest how to design the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on running multiple threads, I suggest you take a look at LoadUI. LoadUI does exactly that. Takes a SoapUI test, and runs it in multiple threads simultaneously.

The delay in your script, can be implemented with a simple Groovy Script, with just one line of code:

```
sleep(1000)
```

The five minute delay should be implemented in LoadUI, or alternately if you launch LoadUI from a commandline, then the script launching LoadUI should implement the five minute delay before it launches LoadUI again.